# how do i get pending group posts from facebook fql

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-php-sdk

I am the group owner from said group. I am using an User token to access the wall posts like so:

```sql
SELECT post_id,
       source_id,
       actor_id,
       target_id,
       message,
       like_info,
       comment_info,
       created_time,
       attachment,
       timeline_visibility,
       privacy,
       is_hidden,
       is_published
FROM   stream
WHERE  type = 308
       AND source_id  = "482501211816484"
ORDER BY created_time DESC
```

How I can I get posts pending approval? am I using the wrong table? Is this possible with FQL or even with Graph?

Answer (score 4):

To check whether a post (in a group) in approved or not-

1. `GET` the details of the concerning post using Graph API -

   ```
   $result = $facebook->api("/POST_ID");
   ```
2. If the post is not approved yet, the keys: `actions` and `subscribed` would be missing from the result; this is because these posts are not eligible for these keys. So, you can create a check using either of the keys. *For eg*,

   ```
   if (array_key_exists("actions",$result))
      // the post is approved
   else
      // not approved
   ```

Comment: how would those Ids be retrieved?  $facebook->api("/groups_id?fields=feed.fields(id,message)"); does not pull it neither does the fwl in the question.

Comment: Use this - `GROUP_ID/feed?fields=id,message`

Comment: I have granted myself all permissions. I am the owner of the group. I used the Graphs API Explorer tool. In the path I put /482501211816484/feed?fields=id,message and the 2 pending status updates do not show up. I go to the group page  https://www.facebook.com/groups/482501211816484/pending/ where i see 2 pending updates. I approve one and go back to the Graph Explorer. It now shows up. I want to test your answer but without a way to retrieve the post ids of pending requests. i do not know how i can test it.

Comment: I got you, you're right. I'll let you know if I found any solution.